# Const Correctness for Getter Function

Tags: c++

Here's a simple question regarding const correctness.

I have this class:

```
template <class T>
class Foo
{
public:
    std::map<std::string, boost::any> members; 

    template <typename T>
    std::vector<T>& member(const std::string& memberName) 
    {
        return boost::any_cast<std::vector<T>&>(members[memberName]);
    }
};
```

I then have a functor which includes the following:

```
bool operator()(Foo& foo) const
{
    std::vector<T> & member = foo.member<T>(_memberName);
```

What confuses me here is that I cant pass Foo by reference to const, since I'm calling the non const member getter function. With regard to its signature, this gives the impression that operator() changes foo.

Should I correct this and if so how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The usual way is to add a `const` overload for the member function:

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<T> const & member(const std::string& memberName) const
{              ^^^^^                                         ^^^^^
    return boost::any_cast<std::vector<T> const &>(members.at(memberName));
}                                         ^^^^^            ^^
```

Calling the member on a `const Foo` will choose this overload; calling it on a non-`const` 
will choose the original one.

Note that `at()` is a fairly new addition to `std::map`. If you're stuck with an outdated library, you'll need something like:

```
std::map<std::string, boost::any>::const_iterator found = members.find(memberName);
if (found == members.end()) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Couldn't find " + memberName);
}
return boost::any_cast<std::vector<T> const &>(found->second);
```

Answer (score 2):

The const correctness applies on the object, whose method you execute. So:

```
bool operator()(Foo& foo) const
```

means that `operator()` will not change anything in the functor class, like the `_memberName` (which seems to be a member of the functor class).

The way it is defined, it is allowed to change Foo (call non-const methods).

**EDIT**:
See [Mike Seymour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/204847/mike-seymour)'s answer as it describes a way to fix it. I personally have done that a lot but didn't seem to get exactly your question. :)

Comment: But the question is, can we arrange to pass `foo` by `const` reference?